# How can I synchronously return the result of an asynchronous process of unknown sequence?

Tags: matlab, asynchronous

Consider an expensive computational process that scales very well no matter how much data it operates on, that needs to be made available in an interactive MATLAB environment where new data can be generated at any moment. If new data arrives while an instance of the process is already underway, I want to abandon that process and restart for all the existing data together, so that the results for all known data so far become available at the earliest opportunity.

However, the early instances of the process may be triggered by synchronous function calls that I still want to return a value once the replacement process has completed.

The following minimal example class recreates this sort of behaviour: it has a method for adding elements to a stored array and a main work method that simply multiplies all stored data so far by `2` after first doing something slow. The work method `DoWork` is invoked asynchronously using `parfeval` so that any incomplete calls can be `cancel`led without compromising the eventual output result.

```
classdef ExampleClass < handle
    properties
        InputData
        OutputData
    end

    properties (Hidden, Transient)
        WorkFuture parallel.Future
    end
    
    methods
        function obj = ExampleClass()
            uibutton(uifigure, ButtonPushedFcn = @(~,evt) obj.AddData(evt.Source.Parent.CurrentPoint(1)));
        end

        function output = DoWork(obj)
            pause(2);
            drawnow
            output = obj.InputData * 2;
        end

        function val = StoreOutput(obj,val)
            obj.OutputData = val;
        end

        function F = AddData(obj,val)
            obj.WorkFuture.cancel;
            obj.InputData(end+1) = val;
            F = parfeval(parallel.Pool.empty,@obj.DoWork,1).afterAll(@obj.StoreOutput,1);
            obj.WorkFuture = F;
        end
    end
end
```

Instantiating the class `h = ExampleClass;` creates a `uifigure` with a button to feed new data (the mouse X-coordinate) into the object. Clicking it a few times in succession will consistently lead to that many elements stored in the `InputData` property, with the resulting outputs of the same number stored in `OutputData` within 2 seconds of the last click.

Now suppose there is a synchronous function that needs a result from this process which includes the output for input value `n`. If it is the only client of the process it can get this result by calling:

```
result = h.AddData(n).fetchOutputs;
```

and this will return as required. However, if the button is clicked to add more input data while the work is still being completed, the `Future` returned from `AddData` is cancelled and so the result is an error:

```
Error using parallel.Future/fetchOutputs
One or more futures resulted in an error.

Caused by:
    Execution of the future was cancelled.
```

Shortly after the error, the required data containing the output for input `n` still ends up stored in `h`, but that information fails to reach the serial process `result = h.AddData(n).fetchOutputs;`.

Is there way to define a synchronous call that has the same intended effect (triggers an asynchronous process and eventually returns a value when that process completes) that can tolerate the cancellation of the initial asynchronous process that it triggers?

This might take the form of a `Future` "passing the baton" of responsibility to another rather than simply ceasing to be valid, or notifying an event that serial code can somehow await, but neither concept has a clear means of implementation to me, so any solution capable of doing either of these things or solving the problem some third way would be welcome.

Comment: Your question contains 6 paragraphs. 5 of 6 paragraphs are devoted to what you have tried so far but the first paragraph ,the most important, is the only paragraph that explains what you are trying to do that I think is incomplete. Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @rahnema1 that is not really accurate, but nonetheless reflects that as written it was hard to read. Previously it was a paragraph of context, followed by an example illustrating that context, followed by a statement of the actual problem within that context. I have front-loaded the statement of "what I am trying to do" to the second paragraph of the question, and explained the application of the problem to the example more carefully; hopefully that makes it clearer?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there way to define a synchronous call that has the same intended effect (triggers an asynchronous process and eventually returns a value when that process completes) that can tolerate the cancellation of the initial asynchronous process that it triggers?

That would be with an implementation of `ExampleClass` that ensures the synchronous call waits for the completion of the latest asynchronous process, even if the original process it initiated was canceled.
That can be achieved by maintaining a reference to the latest [`Future` object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/parallel.future.html) and using a loop to [wait until the computation completes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/parallel.future.wait.html):

```matlab
classdef ExampleClass < handle
    properties
        InputData
        OutputData
        LatestFuture parallel.Future
    end
    
    methods
        function obj = ExampleClass()
            uibutton(uifigure, 'ButtonPushedFcn', @(~,evt) obj.AddData(evt.Source.Parent.CurrentPoint(1)));
            obj.LatestFuture = parallel.Future;
        end

        function output = DoWork(obj)
            pause(2); % Simulate a slow process
            output = obj.InputData * 2;
        end

        function StoreOutput(obj, val)
            obj.OutputData = val;
        end

        function F = AddData(obj, val)
            if ~isempty(obj.WorkFuture) && isvalid(obj.WorkFuture)
                cancel(obj.WorkFuture);
            end
            obj.InputData(end+1) = val;
            F = parfeval(@obj.DoWork, 1);
            obj.WorkFuture = F;
            obj.LatestFuture = F;
        end

        function output = SyncGetData(obj, val)
            F = obj.AddData(val);
            while ~strcmp(F.State, 'finished')
                pause(0.1); % Wait for the latest future to finish
                if ~isempty(obj.LatestFuture) && isvalid(obj.LatestFuture)
                    F = obj.LatestFuture;
                end
            end
            output = fetchOutputs(F);
        end
    end
end
```

The `LatestFuture` property tracks the most recent asynchronous computation. The `AddData` method is modified to update `LatestFuture` whenever a new computation is started. A new method `SyncGetData` does wait for the result of the latest computation, even if the original one is canceled.

```
+----------------------+
| SyncGetData          |
| +------------------+ |
| |  Call AddData    |-----> Starts new async process
| +------------------+ |
| |  Wait Loop       |-----> Waits for the latest Future
| +------------------+ |       to complete
| |  Fetch Output    |-----> Retrieves result from the latest
| +------------------+ |       completed process
+----------------------+
```

Instead of directly calling `h.AddData(n).fetchOutputs;` for synchronous results, you should now use `result = h.SyncGetData(n);`.

---

> This looks like it should work but in doing so block execution on the main thread with the pause calls, which depending on the ratio of calls to `AddData` to cancellations completions could have quite an impact on overall performance.
>
> Is there some way that line could return control to other functions pending execution on that thread rather than pausing it for an arbitrary length of time?

True, the `pause` function does indeed halt execution, which might not be ideal if there are other tasks that need to run concurrently.

To mitigate this, you can use a non-blocking approach that allows MATLAB to continue processing other events and callbacks while waiting for the asynchronous process to complete.

Instead of repeatedly checking the state of the `Future` object, set up a callback that MATLAB will call once the `Future` object's state changes to `'finished'`.

And use [`afterAll`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/parallel.future.afterall.html), a method of the `Future` class that schedules a callback to be executed once a set of futures (in this case, just the latest one) completes.

```matlab
function output = SyncGetData(obj, val)
    F = obj.AddData(val);
    waitFuture = F.afterAll(@obj.RetrieveOutput);
    output = fetchOutputs(waitFuture);
end

function RetrieveOutput(obj)
    % Callback function to handle the output
    if ~isempty(obj.LatestFuture) && isvalid(obj.LatestFuture)
        obj.OutputData = fetchOutputs(obj.LatestFuture);
    end
end
```

`RetrieveOutput` is a new method that handles the output retrieval. It is called automatically when the future (`LatestFuture`) is finished.

---

> It looks like this updated solution handles cancellation and replacement of the future returned by `AddData` exactly once, but not for subsequent cancellations.
>
> That first cancellation completes the future assigned to `F` within `SyncGetData` and so triggers `RetrieveOutput`, but `RetrieveOutput` will then obtain the replacement future `obj.LatestFuture`.
>
> If that future has not yet completed then `fetchOutputs` will wait for it to complete, and if that replacement is also cancelled `fetchOutputs` will fail.

True: the problem is `SyncGetData` handles only one level of cancellation and replacement. If the `Future` object referred to by `LatestFuture` is canceled and replaced again before `RetrieveOutput` fetches its outputs, it could lead to a failure.

So, instead of relying on a single callback to handle the output retrieval, you might have to continuously monitor the state of `LatestFuture` and adapt to changes. Implement a mechanism where `RetrieveOutput` re-schedules itself if it detects that the future it is trying to fetch from has been canceled and replaced. And modify `RetrieveOutput` to check the state of `LatestFuture` before attempting to fetch outputs: if `LatestFuture` is canceled, schedule a new callback.

```matlab
function RetrieveOutput(obj)
    if ~isempty(obj.LatestFuture) && isvalid(obj.LatestFuture)
        if strcmp(obj.LatestFuture.State, 'finished')
            obj.OutputData = fetchOutputs(obj.LatestFuture);
        elseif strcmp(obj.LatestFuture.State, 'failed')
            % Reschedule the callback for the new LatestFuture
            waitFuture = obj.LatestFuture.afterAll(@obj.RetrieveOutput);
        end
    end
end
```

Now, `RetrieveOutput` method checks if `LatestFuture` has finished. If so, it fetches the outputs.
If `LatestFuture` is canceled, it sets up a new callback with `afterAll` for the new `LatestFuture`.
That should make sure that, if multiple cancellations occur, the system adapts and waits for the eventual completion of the latest process.
And it should handle multiple cancellations and replacements of the `Future` object.

You would have:

```bash
+---------------------+
|    ExampleClass     |
| +-----------------+ |
| |  InputData      | |   <---- New data input
| +-----------------+ |
| |  OutputData     | |   <---- Stored result
| +-----------------+ |
| |  WorkFuture     |----> Asynchronous process (DoWork)
| +-----------------+ |     Cancelled and restarted on new data
| |  LatestFuture   |----> Tracks latest Future, updated on restart
| +-----------------+ |
| |  SyncGetData    | |   <---- Synchronous call initiates process
| +-----------------+ |
| |  RetrieveOutput | |   <---- Callback function
| +-----------------+ |       - Checks Future status
|                     |       - Fetches output or reschedules
+---------------------+
```

---

The key issue is ensuring that `SyncGetData` correctly waits for the most recent data processing to complete, even if there are cancellations. Since the cancellation is stored in the `Error` property, we should check for this instead of relying on the `Status` property. You need to make sure `SyncGetData` does not return prematurely and waits for the correct completion of the asynchronous task.

```matlab
classdef ExampleClass < handle
    properties
        InputData
        OutputData
        LatestFuture parallel.Future
    end
    
    methods
        % (Other methods remain the same)

        function output = SyncGetData(obj, val)
            obj.AddData(val);
            output = obj.WaitForCompletion();
        end

        function output = WaitForCompletion(obj)
            while true
                try
                    % Fetch output if the latest future is finished
                    if ~isempty(obj.LatestFuture) && isvalid(obj.LatestFuture)
                        output = fetchOutputs(obj.LatestFuture);
                        break; % Break the loop on successful completion
                    end
                catch e
                    % Handle the cancellation error
                    if strcmp(e.identifier, 'parallel:future:CancelledExecution')
                        continue; % Continue the loop for the new LatestFuture
                    else
                        rethrow(e); % Rethrow other errors
                    end
                end
            end
        end

        function RetrieveOutput(obj)
            % Adjusted to handle cancellation error
            if ~isempty(obj.LatestFuture) && isvalid(obj.LatestFuture)
                if ~isempty(obj.LatestFuture.Error) && ...
                   strcmp(obj.LatestFuture.Error.identifier, 'parallel:future:CancelledExecution')
                    % Reschedule the callback for the new LatestFuture
                    obj.LatestFuture.afterAll(@obj.RetrieveOutput);
                else
                    % Fetch the output normally
                    obj.OutputData = fetchOutputs(obj.LatestFuture);
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

`RetrieveOutput` is revised to check the `Error` property for cancellation and reschedule itself if necessary.

Comment: This looks like it should work but in doing so block execution on the main thread with the `pause` calls, which depending on the ratio of calls to `AddData` to cancellations completions could have quite an impact on overall performance. Is there some way that line could return control to other functions pending execution on that thread rather than pausing it for an arbitrary length of time?

Comment: @Will I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: it looks like this updated solution handles cancellation and replacement of the future returned by `AddData` exactly once but not for subsequent cancellations. That first cancellation completes the future assigned to `F` within `SyncGetData` and so triggers `RetrieveOutput`, but `RetrieveOutput` will then obtain the replacement future `obj.LatestFuture`. If that future has not yet completed then `fetchOutputs` will wait for it to complete, and if that replacement is also cancelled `fetchOutputs` will fail.

Comment: @Will Good point. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: using recursion like this looks extremely promising, however the code doesn't seem to work when tested. After fixing a few straightforward errors (for instance `cancelled` isn't a valid `Status`, the cancellation is stored in the `Error` property) I found that cancellation would cause `SyncGetData` to return early with the most recent value of `OutputData` *before* processing the new data it was given. I will try and work out what needs to change a little later but a working example would certainly be welcome if it's more obvious to you how to fix this

Comment: @Will I have included another approach (but not fully tested).

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you're dealing with a task that works independently but might get stopped if new data shows up. When you use a tool called '`parfeval`' to kick off this task, you might run into a hiccup – a cancellation error – when you try to get the results. So, to smooth things out, you tweak the '`AddData`' method. Now, it checks whether the previous 'Future' is canceled. If it is, it cooks up a new 'Future' for the ongoing task. And if it's not canceled, it cancels the previous 'Future' and whips up a fresh one. This tweak ensures that even if the initial task gets canceled, the synchronous request can still smoothly grab the result.

**Updated `AddData` method**

```
function F = AddData(obj, val)
    % Future not empty canceled , if any
    if ~isempty(obj.WorkFuture)
        obj.WorkFuture.cancel;
    end

    % Store the new data
    obj.InputData(end+1) = val;

    % Creating the new  Future to continue ongoing process
    ongoingFuture = parfeval(parallel.Pool.empty, @obj.DoWork, 1).afterAll(@obj.StoreOutput, 1);

    % WorkFuture updated with ongoingFuture  Future 
    obj.WorkFuture = ongoingFuture;

    % Return  new Future to fetch  outputs synchronously
    F = parfeval(parallel.Pool.empty, @() fetchOutputs(ongoingFuture), 1);
end
```

Now with this what've done is just instead of using the same `Future` from `obj.WorkFuture` why we just not creating a new `Future` and return it as for output fetching , this synchronous call will not be  tied with the cancel status of the ongoing process. in other words the call will proceed no matter of the initial asynchronous process is canceled

This update checks if the previous `WorkFuture` is cancelled before trying to create a new one. If it's cancelled, it creates a new Future for the ongoing process. If it's not cancelled, it cancels the previous Future and creates a new one. Now when you call `h.AddData(n).fetchOutputs` , it will continue to fetch the result even if the initial asynchronous process is cancelled. The synchronous call adapts to the cancellation by creating a new Future for the ongoing work.

Comment: The code here doesn't seem to do what you say it does; runs exactly the same `obj.WorkFuture = ...` line at the end of both branches of the `if` statement so might as well take that back outside. The only difference between branches seems to be whether there is a `cancel` call (and only avoids calling `cancel` on empty or cancelled `Future` arrays, which already had no effect) and whether data passed to `AddData` gets stored or discarded, when I always want to store it. The `Future` passed to `fetchOutputs` remains stored in `obj` and so liable to cancellation before it completes.

Comment: @Will I'm not sure about the doubled `obj.WorkFuture =` in both `if` i think maybe it happened when i modified my answer later this day , Now regarding the code doesn't seem to do what you say it does , I've reread your question to see if i missed something but i noticed  from what i understood of your question error is that the 'Future returned from AddData is cancelled and so the result is an error' i mean yes it should cause error cause fetchoutputs try to fetch result from canceled Future  ,you're canceling `obj.WorkFuture` before storing data , creating the Future due `afterAll` reached

Comment: that is certainly the expected behaviour of the example set up in the question, and that behaviour will remain so long as the synchronous call is `AddData(...).fetchOutputs` and the `Future` returned by `AddData` is the same one that is stored in `obj.WorkFuture` and therefore subject to cancellation. At least one of these things seems like it must change; the question is therefore how it can be changed to achieve the intended behaviour.

Comment: @Will Now i understand what you want we can solve this by just creating a new Future and return it instead of returning the same Future for output  ,Please see my updated answer the code part and below it